# Node JS: Executing command lines and getting outputs asynchronously

Tags: linux, node.js, asynchronous, command-line, output

How can I run a command line and get the outputs as soon as available to show them somewhere.

For example if a run ping command on a linux system, it will never stop, now is it possible to get the responses while the command is still processing ?
Or let's take `apt-get install` command, what if i want to show the progress of the installation as it is running ?

Actually i'm using this function to execute command line and get outputs, but the function will not return until the command line ends, so if i run a ping command it will never return!

```
var sys     = require('sys'),
    exec    = require('child_process').exec;

function getOutput(command,callback){
    exec(
        command, 
        (
            function(){
                return function(err,data,stderr){
                    callback(data);
                }
            }
        )(callback)
    );
}
```

Comment: Try using spawn instead of exec, then you can tap into the stream and listen to the data and end events.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i'm not very familiar with node, just starting whit it, so a little code example, will be very helpful

Answer (score 6):

Try using spawn instead of exec, then you can tap into the stream and listen to the data and end events.

```
var process = require('child_process');

var cmd = process.spawn(command);

cmd.stdout.on('data', function(output){
    console.log(output.toString()):
});

cmd.on('close', function(){
    console.log('Finished');
});

//Error handling
cmd.stderr.on('data', function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```

See the Node.js documentation for `spawn` here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options

Comment: how does it handling error, i added a listener on `cmd.stdout.on('error',...` and i want to do so with process object, but `process.on(...` is not working.

Comment: For error handling you need to listen on stderr. I've added it into my example. You can't add a listener to process, you need to add it to the spawn.

Comment: even with that, i'm still getting an `Unhandled 'error' Event`  while executing a ping command for a test                                                                            `node server.js
<Buffer 65 78 65 63 76 70 28 29 3a 20 4e 6f 20 73 75 63 68 20 66 69 6c 65 20 6f 72 20 64 69 72 65 63 74 6f 72 79 0a>
Finished

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)`

Comment: @Xsmael you need to just enter your args as a list, for example: var cmd = process.spawn('ping', ['1.1.1.1']) You can use a shell lexer (like libraries.io/npm/shlex ) to do this for you if you're not sure what your args will look like (ie, if you're writing a wrapper and need to be concerned with spaces.) Also note the security concerns in the documentation link.